# Get Printer Names and number of trays

Tags: c#, asp.net, printers, tray, network-printers

I was trying to display all available printer names on the server and number of trays associated to them. How to display number of trays associated to the printer?

I used the following code. It works but it doesn't display communicate with the all the information. Should I include messageBox? How to display all these information?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Printing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Management;

namespace Find
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
        foreach (var printer in printerQuery.Get())
        {
            var name = printer.GetPropertyValue("Name");
            var status = printer.GetPropertyValue("Status");
            var isDefault = printer.GetPropertyValue("Default");
            var isNetworkPrinter = printer.GetPropertyValue("Network");

            Console.WriteLine("{0} (Status: {1}, Default: {2}, Network: {3}",
                        name, status, isDefault, isNetworkPrinter);


          }


      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What information is missing?

Comment: it doesn't display anything. When I'm doing debugging, I see the results and the name of the printers in local window. I would like to display all the information in the new window.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. It's likely that your console window is displaying the information very quickly and then exiting. Try adding `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your Main method, so that the Console session remains after displaying the information.

At the end of your Main method, add something like:

```
Console.Write("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```